# Append two dataframes (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Very basic issue, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong. As a result of a Logistic Regression model, I have a set of predictions. I turned that numpy array into a dataframe (single column). Now I want to 'attach' the results to my original data, so I can check my predictions. Seems so simple, but I get the following message:

RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
result = result.union(other)

Sample Looks like this:

```
Set
ColA, ColB, ColC
1234, AAAA, BBBB

Pred
0 -- column name
1 -- values

Desired result:
ColA, ColB, ColC, 0
1234, AAAA, BBBB, 1

Actual result:
ColA, ColB, ColC, NaN
NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  1

My code seems straightforward:

res = Set.append(Pred)
res
```

Any help with this issue would be great. As you might see, I am at a beginner level in Pandas...

Regards, M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create default indices:

```
Set = Set.reset_index(drop=True)
Pred = Pred.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
res = Set.join(Pred)
```

Or [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
res = pd.concat([Set, Pred], axis=1)
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) if `Pred` is `Series`:

```
res = Set.assign(Pred=Pred)
```

Comment: Well, I must be overseeing something, but they all give me the same result. Is my index col (ColA) on Set the issue?  Thanks for your input thusfar. Probably all valid options, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @SQL_M - Yes, it is possible, need `Set = Set.reset_index(drop=True)
Pred= Pred.reset_index(drop=True)` in first step

Comment: I reset the index and now it works!! I used the assign method. Thanks!!